# How to add SSO for cardAction in a ConversationBot which generated from Teams Toolkit?

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

For a ConversationBot which generated from TeamsFx, how can we implement SSO for cardAction? We can have ssoCommands for Command, but it seems like there is sso for cardAction. anyone can show a sample for that?

```
export const commandBot = new ConversationBot({
    // The bot id and password to create CloudAdapter.
    // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
    adapterConfig: {
        MicrosoftAppId: config.botId,
        MicrosoftAppPassword: config.botPassword,
        MicrosoftAppType: "MultiTenant",
    },
    ssoConfig: {
        aad: {
            scopes: ["User.Read"],
        },
    },
    command: {
        enabled: true,
        commands: [new HelloWorldCommandHandler()],
        ssoCommands: [new ProfileSsoCommandHandler()],
    },
    cardAction: { 
       enabled: true, 
       actions: [ 
         new DoSomethingActionHandler() 
       ], 
     },
    notification: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a sso adaptive card sample here: https://github.com/SLdragon/bot-sso-action-card

To use the sample code, you can just clone the repo, open it in VSCode (with Teams Toolkit 4.x.x installed), and click f5 to local debug it.

In the bot chat window, input “helloworld” message, it would response an adaptive card, in the card, there is button which will trigger sso action handler.

> The above sample is just a workaround solution to make the sso works for adaptive card with modified teamsfx sdk, and it doesn't work in group chat, and in the future, teams toolkit team will provide a stable solution for it using new GA feature describe as below

You can also try latest GA features for universal sso card action (It is not integrate with teams toolkit now, but you can follow the steps in sample project to make it work):

The document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/enable-sso-for-your-adaptive-cards-universal-action

Sample project: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-sso-adaptivecard/nodejs